# Laravel The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to run Skills function but I cant it.

Route.php

```
Route::get('setting',function(){
    return \App\User::first()->skills();
});
```

User.php

```
protected $casts = [
    'skills' => 'json'
];

public function skills(){
    return new Skills($this , $this->skills);
}
```

Skills.php

```
namespace App;
use App\User;
use Mockery\Exception;

class Skills
{
    protected $user;
    protected $skills = [];

    public function __construct(User $user,array $skills){

        $this->user=$user;
        $this->skills=$skills;
    }
}
```

I want to enter /settings page I have "`The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`" error.

I tried to add `dd()` function's return in route, I see all JSON data but `$skills->get()`, `$skill->set()` didn't working at the time.

Edit:

Skills.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: root
     * Date: 01.08.2015
     * Time: 11:45
     */

    namespace App;
    use App\User;
    use Mockery\Exception;

    class Skills
    {
        protected $user;
        protected $skills = [];

        public function __construct(User $user,array $skills){
            $this->user=$user;
            $this->skills=$skills;
        }

        public function get($key){
            return array_get($this->skills,$key);
        }

        public function set($key,$value){
            $this->skills[$key]=$value;
            return $this->duration();
        }

        public function has($key){
            return array_key_exists($key,$this->skills);
        }

        public function all(){
           return $this->skills;
        }

        public function merge(array $attributes){
            $this->skills = array_merge(
                $this->skills,
                array_only(
                    $attributes,
                    array_keys($this->skills)
                )
            );
            return $this->duration();
        }

        public function duration(){
            return $this->user->update(['skills' => $this->skills]);
        }

        public function __get($key){
            if ($this->has($key)) {
                return $this->get($key);
            }
            throw new Exception("{$key} adlı Yetenek bulunamadı");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
return \App\User::first()->skills();
```

you are returning the Relation definition object, which doesn't implement **__toString()** method. What you need in order to return the related object is

```
return \App\User::first()->skills;
```

This will return a **Collection** object cotaining related skills - this will be properly serialized.

Comment: Thanks for Answer I'm trying

but I want to run 

 \App\User::first()->skills()->set("HTML","100");
        return \App\User::first()->skills;

İts not set :)

Comment: And what is that set() function supposed to do? What version of Laravel are you using? I cannot see anything like that in the Laravel's code

Comment: Oh, I thought skills() is a one-to-many relation between User and Skills, not some custom function

Comment: Ok, 2 things. If you want to return Skills object from the controller, it needs to implement __toString() method - it doesn't and that's why you're getting the error. And what you're doing in your code is very unusual with Laravel - you seem to implement some kind of relation but do this yourself instead of using Eloquent's functionality. Have a look at the docs to see how to define relationships between models: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

May be you could go with `get_object_vars($skills)` and later `loop` through the object variables. 
Example:

```
foreach(get_object_vars($skills) as $prop => $val){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the **Route.php**, return a collection like so

```
Route::get('setting',function(){
     return \App\User::first()->skills;
});
```

OR

```
Route::get('setting',function(){
    $skills = \App\User::first(['id','skills']);
    return $skills->skills;
});
```

And on you User.php model, you can factor your code say so

```
protected $casts = [
    'skills' => 'json'
];

public function skills()
{
    return $this->skills;
}
```

I hope this helps someone.